# JQuery script not working - Newbie

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm working on adding a jaccordion to my website. Here's the thing, I've tested it in CodePen and it works fine, but when I try it in my browser, no dice and nothing I do seems to change that. I feel like it must be something as simple as calling the external file for the script, but I've tried everything I can think of to that end (FYI: all of the files for this are stored in a folder called SheilaWebsite, with introsong.html as a standalone. The file accordion.js is in the folder js).

I'm a real neophyte when it comes to Jquery, so I could use some help.

Here's the CodePen link so you can see the html and .js files: http://codepen.io/maryrizzo/pen/CowLD

Thank you!!!!

Mary

Comment: Without the code on your real site, we can't help you.  But, I can make a strong guess that you aren't including the jQuery library in your real site - Read this for a fast way to get jQuery loaded: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: "It's not working" explains almost nothing. Help us to help you, use your browser's Developer console to track errors, focus on the issue, than post some code with a valid and specific question...

Comment: OK... to start from somewhere... the JS part from Codepen, where exactly are you putting it inside your project?

Comment: Hi all. 1st, the Codepen code is all of the real code. This is a standalone page of html, css and the .js. I believe that the Jquery library is being called in the head tag.

Comment: Hi all. Sorry for being vague with "it's not working." What I should've said is that when tested in Codepen, the accordion pulls in the information from the div and puts it into the sliding tabs. When I test the same local files in my browser, it's just text. No accordion. As for including the jquery library, I've got this in the head tag. Is it what you mean? <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @user3650823 The above is correct, first goes jQ, than the UI. But, I'll ask again. In the Codepen you shared (you clearly don't use codepen in your real project), the JS part, where is exactly embedded that JS code in your project? Also you have an error there, you should remove the last comma from `collapsible: true,`. Again, I'll ask again... have you opened your Developer's Console and checked for possible errors?

Comment: @user3650823 Also if the codepen is the code you exactly use in your real project, than don't *believe*. Be *sure*.

Comment: I suspect you may be trying to run this from local file, ie `file://path` in browser address bar. Some browsers won't access external resources doing this unless you run on localhost server. If this is case their might be security settngs you can adjust to allow it

Comment: Thanks for the advice to check the Developer console (newbie, remember!). That got me the error message and then I realized that it wasn't finding the files I needed to get JS to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your HTML file locally from the file system and not from a web server, then the code you are using to bring in your external JavaScript dependencies will not work.  When you use "//" without specifying a protocol, this is the same as saying "use the same protocol my browser used to request this page".  For example, if you requested a page like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.html
```

then all of the requests for the script files will use http.  If you request it like this:

```
https://www.domain.com/myfile.html
```

then all of the requests will use https/ssl.  If you request it like this:

```
file://pathtofile/myfile.html
```

then the requests will try to retrieve the script files using file.  Obviously, this will not work.  You can either specify http or https in the src attribute of your script tag or make sure you do your testing on a web server.  There are several that are freely available that you can install locally or setup a free dev account at a site like AppHarbor.